# Video stream not displayed on Tkinter screen

Tags: python, opencv, tkinter

[image: screen_tkinter]

I've created a class Tela which is basically is my Screen and I'm trying to display the webcam video on a Tkinter GUI. My webcam LED is on but the label "painel" where I want do show my video is grey. Can someone tell me what's wrong with my code. I appreciate.

```
class Tela:
def __init__(self, janela):
    self.janela = janela
    self.janela.title("Reconhecimento Facial")
    self.janela.config(background="#FFFFFF")

    # Open camera
    self.cam = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    self.detector = dlib.get_frontal_face_detector()

    self.quadro = tkinter.Frame(janela, width=600, height=500)
    self.quadro.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=10, pady=2, rowspan=3)

    self.painel = tkinter.Label(self.quadro)
    self.quadro.grid(row=0, column=0, rowspan=3)

    # Methods for screen update
    self.delay = 15
    self.update()
    self.janela.mainloop()

def update(self):
    # Get frame 
    ret, frame = self.cam.read()    
    faces, confianca, idx = self.detector.run(frame)
    for i, face in enumerate(faces):
        e, t, d, b = (int(face.left()), int(face.top()), int(face.right()), int(face.bottom()))
        cv2.rectangle(frame, (e, t), (d, b), (0, 255, 255), 2)
    cv2image = cv2.cvtColor(self.frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGBA)
    image = Image.fromarray(cv2image)
    imgtk = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image=image)
    self.painel.imgtk = imgtk
    self.painel.configure(image=imgtk)
    self.janela.after(self.delay, self.update)

   # Creates the window
   Tela(tkinter.Tk())
```

Comment: you have wrong indentions in code. Maybe it is only mistake when you paste code but maybe it is your problem. Put code with correct indentions. And don't forget imported modules.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mistake is in second line

```
 self.painel = tkinter.Label(self.quadro)
 self.quadro.grid(row=0, column=0, rowspan=3)
```

You created `Label` but you don't put it in window - it has to be `self.painel.grid` instead of `self.quadro.grid`

```
 self.painel = tkinter.Label(self.quadro)
 self.painel.grid(row=0, column=0, rowspan=3)
```

Comment: Thanks man! That line was wrong. I fixed it and now it's working fine.